# Verify/Check my proof about power sets?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I think I have a proof of the following theorem but I am not 100% confident with it. Primarily, I am not sure if my two cases are exhaustive. This is my first proof-based math class, and we only started doing proofs last week. So I have little experience with proof writing and could use all the help I can get.

> **Theorem**. Prove that for any sets A and B, if $ \mathscr P(A) \cup \mathscr P(B) =  \mathscr P(A\cup B)$ then either $ A \subseteq B $ or $B \subseteq A$.
>
> **Proof**. Suppose that $\mathscr P(A)\cup\mathscr P(B)=\mathscr P(A\cup B)$. This means that $\mathscr P(A\cup B)\subseteq\mathscr P(A)\cup\mathscr P(B)$. Since every set is a member of its power set $A\cup B$ $\epsilon$ $\mathscr P(A\cup B)$, but $\mathscr P(A\cup B) \subseteq\mathscr P(A) \cup \mathscr P(B)$, thus $A\cup B$ $\epsilon$ $\mathscr P(A)\cup\mathscr P(B)$. Since this means that $A\cup B$ is either an element of $\mathscr P(A)\text{ or }\mathscr P(B)$, we will consider the two cases. Let $\mathit x$ be an arbitrary set.
>
> - Case 1. $A\cup B\text{ }\epsilon\text{ }\mathscr P(A)$. This means that $A\cup B \subseteq A $, thus if $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } A$ or  $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } B$, then $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } A$. When  $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } A$ this is redundant. When  $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } B$, then  $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } A$. Thus $B \subseteq A$.
> - Case 2.  $A\cup B\text{ }\epsilon\text{ }\mathscr P(B)$. This means that $A\cup B \subseteq B $, thus if $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } A$ or  $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } B$, then $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } A$. When  $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } B$ this is redundant. When  $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } A$, then  $\mathit x\text{ }\epsilon\text{ } B$. Thus $A \subseteq B$.
>
> Since $\mathit{x}$ was an arbitrary set and the cases were exhaustive, if $ \mathscr P(A) \cup \mathscr P(B) =  \mathscr P(A\cup B)$, then either $A\subseteq B\text{ or } B\subseteq A$.

If my cases are not exhaustive, could you maybe point why they are not and leave any hints on how to make cases that are exhaustive, or on another strategy to prove the *or* statement. If this proof has any other errors I would appreciate any help regarding those as well.

Comment: There was no reason to point out $P(A\cup B) \subset P(A)\cup P(B)$ when you can use the stronger statement $P(A\cup B) = P(A)\cup P(B)$.

Comment: @fleablood ya i was sort of thinkinng that as i re-typed up the proof for this post. Besides that are there any errors in my logic, or is this a complete proof of the thereom?

Comment: for future reference, you should use `\in` instead of `\epsilon` to typeset $\in$ instead of $\epsilon$

Comment: "Besides that are there any errors in my logic, or is this a complete proof of the thereom?"  Not that I can tell.  Perhaps it's not as clean as yours but my thought would be any subset of  $A\cup B$ must be a subset *entirely* of $A$ or entirely of $B$ which means ... well, it's impossible to have a subset with elements of $A$ not in $B$ and elements of $B$ not in $A$ which can only mean one or the other can't exist.... well, maybe your way is cleaner than mine.